# How to open a presentation document in Keynote on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, keynote

In Keynote app on my iPad, I see a list of seven of my presentations “On My iPad”. Next to these is a list of “Locations” including `iCloud Drive`, `On My iPad`, and `Recently Deleted`.

When I single-tap on the icons, nothing happens. When I double-tap on the icons, nothing happens. If I press-and-hold I get a context menu offering items such as `Copy`, `Duplicate`, `Delete`, and so on. But no `Open`.

➥ How does one convince Keynote to open its own presentation files?

[image: screenshot of presentation files list in Keynote app]

Comment: So this really is about troubleshooting when the tap doesn’t open. Want some ideas what I’d try? I’ve never seen this, but knowing what happens underneath we might make a trouble shooting attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a bug.

Crashed out of Keynote. Relaunched Keynote. Now a single-tap opens the presentation.

Comment: Cool. I almost said restart iOS entirely. Saved application state can be cranky to debug on iOS and macOS.